# Ipynb : Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and multilabel-indicator targets , ValueError

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

Link to the colab notebook - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1o_YO4wJ4xmPOvWfw9fRNxinXE-I2md19#scrollTo=CjykH7STSeju
I'm not able to get a solution to the below-mentioned error. Please Help

```
1030/1030 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1726 - accuracy: 0.9262

accuracy: 92.62%
The AUC FOR transformer approach IS 0.0879245139775392

[[ True False]
 [False  True]
 [ True False]
 ...
 [False  True]
 [ True False]
 [ True False]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-b62407ca5b02> in <module>()
     27 print(y_pred)
     28 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score
---> 29 cm = confusion_matrix(yts, y_pred)
     30 accuracy=accuracy_score(yts,y_pred)
     31 print("Confusion matrix for   transformer approach is",cm)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     88     if len(y_type) > 1:
     89         raise ValueError("Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} "
---> 90                          "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
     91 
     92     # We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no more needed

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and multilabel-indicator targets
```